# IntelliJ cannot import module but works fine from command line

Tags: python, intellij-idea, fipy

I am using Ubuntu and trying to run a simple Python script:

```
from fipy import Grid1D

nx = 50
dx = 1.
mesh = Grid1D(nx=nx, dx=dx)
print(mesh)
```

If I run this from command line everything is fine:

```
dario@dario-X750JB:~$ /home/dario/anaconda2/envs/panaxea/bin/python /home/dario/phdCode/fipy/example.py
UniformGrid1D(dx=1.0, nx=50)
dario@dario-X750JB:~$
```

However, if I run this from within IntelliJ it cannot load the module:

```
/home/dario/anaconda2/envs/panaxea/bin/python /home/dario/phdCode/fipy/example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dario/phdCode/fipy/example.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fipy import Grid1D
ImportError: cannot import name Grid1D

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Note that the python venv and the script which are being executed are exactly the same, so I do not understand why the difference in results.

Anybody has come across something similar?

Note Fipy is definitely installed:

```
dario@dario-X750JB:~$ which python
/home/dario/anaconda2/envs/panaxea/bin/python
dario@dario-X750JB:~$ pip list
Package    Version  
---------- ---------
certifi    2018.4.16
FiPy       3.1.3    
future     0.16.0   
numpy      1.14.5   
pip        10.0.1   
pyglet     1.3.2    
scipy      1.1.0    
setuptools 39.2.0   
wheel      0.31.1   
dario@dario-X750JB:~$
```

Comment: Can you add the following to your script 

 - `import fipy` at the top before anything
 - `print(fipy.__version__)`
 - `print(fipy.__path__)`

Comment: Working now, for some reason IntelliJ wasn't seeing it as a python module even though __init__.py was there. I re-created the directory from within intellij selecting New > Module and that seems to have fixed it.